# Dynamic database tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an idea where I would like to dynamically add tables to my database(through a website). I probably cannot use entity framework then, but I am not sure what the best tools would be.

So the idea is that a user would be able to create new "entities" and therefore create new tables in the database. There are only 3 types of entities(but multiple of each type) that user will be able to create so in theory I could have 3 tables with a entity filter but since there will be millions of records per entity and entities will never be used together I do not want to store them in the same table.

So my initial idea is to create a table per entity, what would be the best way to communicate with the database? Custom data access layer?

I am also open to other suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dapper with dynamic objects, it's really fast and fits exactly your needs.

https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used entity framework.

Firstly I created a template for each type I would have. Lets say TypeA, TypeB and added it to my model. Then I used the model builder to switch between Mappings

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

DbModelBuilder builder = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.V6_0);
builder.Configurations.Add(new EntityTypeConfiguration<TypeA>());

builder.Entity<Tweet>().ToTable("Table1");

using (MyEntities myEntities= new MyEntities (builder.Build(conn).Compile()))
{
    var a = myEntities.Tweets.ToList();//Return table 1
}

DbModelBuilder builder2 = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.V6_0);
builder2.Configurations.Add(new EntityTypeConfiguration<TypeA>());
builder2.Entity<TypeA>().ToTable("Table2");

using (MyEntities myEntities= new MyEntities (builder.Build(conn).Compile()))
{
    var a = myEntities.Tweets.ToList();//Return table 2
}
```